# Rails 5.2 Error Changing or Removing Table Column (SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed: DROP TABLE)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I'm trying to accomplish the fairly simple feat of changing the default value for one of the columns from my `Blog` table.  I have the following migration:

```
class UpdateBlogFields < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    change_column :blogs, :freebie_type, :string, default: "None"
  end
end
```

Fairly simple, but I'm getting the following error when I run `rake db:migrate`:

```
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed: DROP TABLE "blogs"
```

I get this error any time I try to change or remove a column, but not when adding one.

My schema looks like this:

```
  create_table "blogs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.string "teaser"
    t.text "body"
    t.string "category", default: "General"
    t.string "linked_module"
    t.boolean "published", default: false
    t.datetime "published_on"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "image_id"
    t.integer "pdf_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "slug"
    t.string "cta_read_more", default: "Read More"
    t.string "cta_pdf", default: "Get My Free PDF"
    t.string "cta_video", default: "Watch the Video"
    t.string "convertkit_data_form_toggle"
    t.string "convertkit_href"
    t.integer "pin_image_id"
    t.string "data_pin_description"
    t.string "freebie_filename"
    t.string "video_link"
    t.string "freebie_type", default: "File"
    t.string "freebie_description"
    t.integer "comments_count"
    t.integer "subcategory_id"
    t.boolean "affiliate_links", default: true
    t.boolean "approved", default: false
    t.boolean "submitted", default: false
    t.index ["image_id"], name: "index_blogs_on_image_id"
    t.index ["pdf_id"], name: "index_blogs_on_pdf_id"
    t.index ["pin_image_id"], name: "index_blogs_on_pin_image_id"
    t.index ["slug"], name: "index_blogs_on_slug", unique: true
    t.index ["subcategory_id"], name: "index_blogs_on_subcategory_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_blogs_on_user_id"
  end
```

It seems that this might be an SQLite thing, because [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47347421/error-removing-column-rails) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53354868/why-does-rails-want-to-drop-a-table-just-to-rename-a-column-sqlite) seem to be having a similar problem.  However, neither post involves an actual answer.  Has anyone successfully gotten rid of this?

Comment: can you show the schema for the table `blog`?

Comment: @devanand I added some more details and my schema.  Do you have any theories on this one?

Comment: I know this isn't relevant here, but why are you using SQLite ? You should really consider using PostgreSQL or MySQL for production environment - or even development.

Comment: @RocKhalil why use a gigantic tool if sqlite fits his needs?

Comment: @sloneorzeszki SQLite is for testing and development environments; using `gigantic` database servers is always the way to go when used in production - they are also open source, no license required.

Comment: @RocKhalil There's really no reason to use more resources than needed. SQLite is a perfectly valid choice for small/medium websites.

Comment: @sloneorzeszki All of the problems in this question are directly because they are using SQLite. I think there are some pretty valid reasons to avoid it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UPDATE:

A new column default can be added via Rails without having to use the database.  In the `Blog` model, we can use [ActiveRecord::Attributes::ClassMethods::attribute](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods.html) to redefine the default value for `freebie_type`:

`attribute :freebie_type, :string, default: 'None'`

This will change the default at the business logic level.  Therefore, it is dependent on using ActiveRecord to be recognized.  Manipulation of the database via SQL will still use the old default. To update the default in all cases see the original answer below.

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

Unfortunately, `ALTER COLUMN` is only [minimally supported](https://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html) by SQLite. The work around it to create a new table, copy the information to it, drop the old table, and finally rename the new table.  This is what Rails is attempting to do, but without first disabling the foreign key constraints. The foreign key relations to `user_id`, `image_id`, and `pdf_id` are preventing the table deletion.

You will need to do the update manually, either with SQL (preferred) or `ActiveRecord::Base.connection`.  You can see the [process here](https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/tables/alter_table.php) under 'Modify column in table'. You can find all the options available for columns in the [SQLite Create Table Documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html).

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=off;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

ALTER TABLE table1 RENAME TO _table1_old;

CREATE TABLE table1 (
( column1 datatype [ NULL | NOT NULL ] DEFAULT (<MY_VALUE>),
  column2 datatype [ NULL | NOT NULL ] DEFAULT (<MY_VALUE>),
  ...
);

INSERT INTO table1 (column1, column2, ... column_n)
  SELECT column1, column2, ... column_n
  FROM _table1_old;

COMMIT;

PRAGMA foreign_keys=on;
```

Be certain that you have all the columns set up the way you want as you will not be able to fix it after the table is created!  Going forward I would highly recommend setting up either a PostgreSQL or MySQL2 database. They are much more powerful and will be much easier to modify and maintain.

Comment: Just to redeem my self somewhat it appears that [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51815720/1978251) offers a reversible mechanism that is essentially your answer boiled down to the foreign key fixes while still leveraging rails migration methods for rollback compatibility

Answer (score 3):

You can add an initializer to monkey patch the sqlite adapter to make it work with rails 5, just make sure you have sqlite >= 3.8, with this code:

```
blog/config/initializers/sqlite3_disable_referential_to_rails_5.rb
```

Content:

```
require 'active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter'

module ActiveRecord
  module ConnectionAdapters
    class SQLite3Adapter < AbstractAdapter

      # REFERENTIAL INTEGRITY ====================================

      def disable_referential_integrity # :nodoc:
        old_foreign_keys = query_value("PRAGMA foreign_keys")
        old_defer_foreign_keys = query_value("PRAGMA defer_foreign_keys")

        begin
          execute("PRAGMA defer_foreign_keys = ON")
          execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF")
          yield
        ensure
          execute("PRAGMA defer_foreign_keys = #{old_defer_foreign_keys}")
          execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = #{old_foreign_keys}")
        end
      end

      def insert_fixtures_set(fixture_set, tables_to_delete = [])
        disable_referential_integrity do
          transaction(requires_new: true) do
            tables_to_delete.each {|table| delete "DELETE FROM #{quote_table_name(table)}", "Fixture Delete"}

            fixture_set.each do |table_name, rows|
              rows.each {|row| insert_fixture(row, table_name)}
            end
          end
        end
      end

      private

      def alter_table(table_name, options = {})
        altered_table_name = "a#{table_name}"
        caller = lambda {|definition| yield definition if block_given?}

        transaction do
          disable_referential_integrity do
            move_table(table_name, altered_table_name,
                       options.merge(temporary: true))
            move_table(altered_table_name, table_name, &caller)
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the gist: https://gist.github.com/javier-menendez/3cfa71452229f8125865a3247fa03d51

Answer (score -4):

first u need to migrate your database rake db:migrate after type this line in your console rails g migration Removevideo_linkFromblogs video_link:string

Comment: I get this error when attempting to `rake db:migrate`, so running it won't fix things.